# I got an error in solidity like "TypeError: "block.blockhash()" has been deprecated in favor of "blockhash()""

Tags: solidity, remix, gemini, etherscan

I get gemini-doller contract code from etherscan through this link"https://etherscan.io/address/0x056fd409e1d7a124bd7017459dfea2f387b6d5cd#code" while test it in remix
i found some errors in line number 28 its like "TypeError: "block.blockhash()" has been deprecated in favor of "blockhash()"" can anyone please resolve it.

```
 pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

    /** @title  A contract for generating unique identifiers
      *
      * @notice  A contract that provides a identifier generation scheme,
      * guaranteeing uniqueness across all contracts that inherit from it,
      * as well as unpredictability of future identifiers.
      *
      * @dev  This contract is intended to be inherited by any contract that
      * implements the callback software pattern for cooperative custodianship.
      *
      * @author  Gemini Trust Company, LLC
      */
    contract LockRequestable {

        // MEMBERS
        /// @notice  the count of all invocations of `generateLockId`.
        uint256 public lockRequestCount;

        // CONSTRUCTOR
       constructor() public {
            lockRequestCount = 0;
        }

        // FUNCTIONS

        function generateLockId() internal returns (bytes32 lockId) {
            return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.blockhash(block.number - 1), address(this), ++lockRequestCount));
        }
    }



    contract CustodianUpgradeable is LockRequestable {

        // TYPES
        /// @dev  The struct type for pending custodian changes.
        struct CustodianChangeRequest {
            address proposedNew;
        }

        // MEMBERS
        /// @dev  The address of the account or contract that acts as the custodian.
        address public custodian;

        /// @dev  The map of lock ids to pending custodian changes.
        mapping (bytes32 => CustodianChangeRequest) public custodianChangeReqs;

        // CONSTRUCTOR
        constructor(
            address _custodian
        )
          LockRequestable()
          public
        {
            custodian = _custodian;
        }

        // MODIFIERS
        modifier onlyCustodian {
            require(msg.sender == custodian);
            _;
        }

        // PUBLIC FUNCTIONS
        // (UPGRADE)


        function requestCustodianChange(address _proposedCustodian) public returns (bytes32 lockId) {
            require(_proposedCustodian != address(0));

            lockId = generateLockId();

            custodianChangeReqs[lockId] = CustodianChangeRequest({
                proposedNew: _proposedCustodian
            });

            emit CustodianChangeRequested(lockId, msg.sender, _proposedCustodian);
        }

        function confirmCustodianChange(bytes32 _lockId) public onlyCustodian {
            custodian = getCustodianChangeReq(_lockId);

            delete custodianChangeReqs[_lockId];

            emit CustodianChangeConfirmed(_lockId, custodian);
        }

        // PRIVATE FUNCTIONS
        function getCustodianChangeReq(bytes32 _lockId) private view returns (address _proposedNew) {
            CustodianChangeRequest storage changeRequest = custodianChangeReqs[_lockId];

            // reject ‘null’ results from the map lookup
            // this can only be the case if an unknown `_lockId` is received

             require(changeRequest.proposedNew != 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000);


            return changeRequest.proposedNew;
        }

        /// @dev  Emitted by successful `requestCustodianChange` calls.
        event CustodianChangeRequested(
            bytes32 _lockId,
            address _msgSender,
            address _proposedCustodian
        );

        /// @dev Emitted by successful `confirmCustodianChange` calls.
        event CustodianChangeConfirmed(bytes32 _lockId, address _newCustodian);
    }



    contract ERC20ImplUpgradeable is CustodianUpgradeable  {

        // TYPES
        /// @dev  The struct type for pending implementation changes.
        struct ImplChangeRequest {
            address proposedNew;
        }

        // MEMBERS
        // @dev  The reference to the active token implementation.
        ERC20Impl public erc20Impl;

        /// @dev  The map of lock ids to pending implementation changes.
        mapping (bytes32 => ImplChangeRequest) public implChangeReqs;

        // CONSTRUCTOR
        constructor(address _custodian) CustodianUpgradeable(_custodian) public {
            erc20Impl = ERC20Impl(0x0);
        }

        // MODIFIERS
        modifier onlyImpl {
            require(msg.sender == address(erc20Impl));
            _;
        }

        // PUBLIC FUNCTIONS
        // (UPGRADE)

        function requestImplChange(address _proposedImpl) public returns (bytes32 lockId) {
            require(_proposedImpl != address(0));

            lockId = generateLockId();

            implChangeReqs[lockId] = ImplChangeRequest({
                proposedNew: _proposedImpl
            });

            emit ImplChangeRequested(lockId, msg.sender, _proposedImpl);
        }

        function confirmImplChange(bytes32 _lockId) public onlyCustodian {
            erc20Impl = getImplChangeReq(_lockId);

            delete implChangeReqs[_lockId];

            emit ImplChangeConfirmed(_lockId, address(erc20Impl));
        }

        // PRIVATE FUNCTIONS
        function getImplChangeReq(bytes32 _lockId) private view returns (ERC20Impl _proposedNew) {
            ImplChangeRequest storage changeRequest = implChangeReqs[_lockId];

            // reject ‘null’ results from the map lookup
            // this can only be the case if an unknown `_lockId` is received
            require(changeRequest.proposedNew != address(0));

            return ERC20Impl(changeRequest.proposedNew);
        }

        /// @dev  Emitted by successful `requestImplChange` calls.
        event ImplChangeRequested(
            bytes32 _lockId,
            address _msgSender,
            address _proposedImpl
        );

        /// @dev Emitted by successful `confirmImplChange` calls.
        event ImplChangeConfirmed(bytes32 _lockId, address _newImpl);
    }


    contract ERC20Interface {

      function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256);

      // https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md#balanceof
      function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance);

      // https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md#transfer
      function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);

      // https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md#transferfrom
      function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);

      // https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md#approve
      function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);

      // https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md#allowance
      function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256 remaining);

      // EVENTS
      // https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md#transfer-1
      event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);

      // https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md#approval
      event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);
    }


    contract ERC20Proxy is ERC20Interface, ERC20ImplUpgradeable {

        // MEMBERS
        /// @notice  Returns the name of the token.
        string public name;

        /// @notice  Returns the symbol of the token.
        string public symbol;

        /// @notice  Returns the number of decimals the token uses.
        uint8 public decimals;

        // CONSTRUCTOR
        constructor(
            string memory _name,
            string memory _symbol,
            uint8 _decimals,
            address _custodian
        )
            ERC20ImplUpgradeable(_custodian)
            public
        {
            name = _name;
            symbol = _symbol;
            decimals = _decimals;
        }

        // PUBLIC FUNCTIONS
        // (ERC20Interface)
        /** @notice  Returns the total token supply.
          *
          * @return  the total token supply.
          */
        function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
            return erc20Impl.totalSupply();
        }

        function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
            return erc20Impl.balanceOf(_owner);
        }

        /** @dev Internal use only.
          */
        function emitTransfer(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public onlyImpl {
            emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        }

        function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
            return erc20Impl.transferWithSender(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        }


        function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
            return erc20Impl.transferFromWithSender(msg.sender, _from, _to, _value);
        }

        /** @dev Internal use only.
          */
        function emitApproval(address _owner, address _spender, uint256 _value) public onlyImpl {
            emit Approval(_owner, _spender, _value);
        }

        /** @notice  Allows `_spender` to withdraw from your account multiple times,
          * up to the `_value` amount. If this function is called again it
          * overwrites the current allowance with _value.
          *
          * @dev  Will fire the `Approval` event.
          *
          * @return  success  true if approval completes.
          */
        function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
            return erc20Impl.approveWithSender(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        }


        function increaseApproval(address _spender, uint256 _addedValue) public returns (bool success) {
            return erc20Impl.increaseApprovalWithSender(msg.sender, _spender, _addedValue);
        }

        function decreaseApproval(address _spender, uint256 _subtractedValue) public returns (bool success) {
            return erc20Impl.decreaseApprovalWithSender(msg.sender, _spender, _subtractedValue);
        }

        /** @notice  Returns how much `_spender` is currently allowed to spend from
          * `_owner`'s balance.
          *
          * @return  remaining  the remaining allowance.
          */
        function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256 remaining) {
            return erc20Impl.allowance(_owner, _spender);
        }
    }



    contract ERC20Impl is CustodianUpgradeable {

        // TYPES
        /// @dev  The struct type for pending increases to the token supply (print).
        struct PendingPrint {
            address receiver;
            uint256 value;
        }

        // MEMBERS
        /// @dev  The reference to the proxy.
        ERC20Proxy public erc20Proxy;

        /// @dev  The reference to the store.
        ERC20Store public erc20Store;

        /// @dev  The sole authorized caller of delegated transfer control ('sweeping').
        address public sweeper;


        bytes32 public sweepMsg;


        mapping (address => bool) public sweptSet;

        /// @dev  The map of lock ids to pending token increases.
        mapping (bytes32 => PendingPrint) public pendingPrintMap;

        // CONSTRUCTOR
        constructor(
              address _erc20Proxy,
              address _erc20Store,
              address _custodian,
              address _sweeper
        )
            CustodianUpgradeable(_custodian)
            public
        {
            require(_sweeper != 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000);
            erc20Proxy = ERC20Proxy(_erc20Proxy);
            erc20Store = ERC20Store(_erc20Store);

            sweeper = _sweeper;
            sweepMsg = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(address(this), "sweep"));
        }

        // MODIFIERS
        modifier onlyProxy {
            require(msg.sender == address(erc20Proxy));
            _;
        }
        modifier onlySweeper {
            require(msg.sender == sweeper);
            _;
        }


        function approveWithSender(
            address _sender,
            address _spender,
            uint256 _value
        )
            public
            onlyProxy
            returns (bool success)
        {
            require(_spender != address(0)); // disallow unspendable approvals
            erc20Store.setAllowance(_sender, _spender, _value);
            erc20Proxy.emitApproval(_sender, _spender, _value);
            return true;
        }

        /** @notice  Core logic of the `increaseApproval` function.
          *
          * @dev  This function can only be called by the referenced proxy,
          * which has an `increaseApproval` function.
          * Every argument passed to that function as well as the original
          * `msg.sender` gets passed to this function.
          * NOTE: approvals for the zero address (unspendable) are disallowed.
          *
          * @param  _sender  The address initiating the approval.
          */
        function increaseApprovalWithSender(
            address _sender,
            address _spender,
            uint256 _addedValue
        )
            public
            onlyProxy
            returns (bool success)
        {
            require(_spender != address(0)); // disallow unspendable approvals
            uint256 currentAllowance = erc20Store.allowed(_sender, _spender);
            uint256 newAllowance = currentAllowance + _addedValue;

            require(newAllowance >= currentAllowance);

            erc20Store.setAllowance(_sender, _spender, newAllowance);
            erc20Proxy.emitApproval(_sender, _spender, newAllowance);
            return true;
        }

        /** @notice  Core logic of the `decreaseApproval` function.
          *
          * @dev  This function can only be called by the referenced proxy,
          * which has a `decreaseApproval` function.
          * Every argument passed to that function as well as the original
          * `msg.sender` gets passed to this function.
          * NOTE: approvals for the zero address (unspendable) are disallowed.
          *
          * @param  _sender  The address initiating the approval.
          */
        function decreaseApprovalWithSender(
            address _sender,
            address _spender,
            uint256 _subtractedValue
        )
            public
            onlyProxy
            returns (bool success)
        {
            require(_spender != address(0)); // disallow unspendable approvals
            uint256 currentAllowance = erc20Store.allowed(_sender, _spender);
            uint256 newAllowance = currentAllowance - _subtractedValue;

            require(newAllowance <= currentAllowance);

            erc20Store.setAllowance(_sender, _spender, newAllowance);
            erc20Proxy.emitApproval(_sender, _spender, newAllowance);
            return true;
        }

        function requestPrint(address _receiver, uint256 _value) public returns (bytes32 lockId) {
            require(_receiver != address(0));

            lockId = generateLockId();

            pendingPrintMap[lockId] = PendingPrint({
                receiver: _receiver,
                value: _value
            });

            emit PrintingLocked(lockId, _receiver, _value);
        }

        function confirmPrint(bytes32 _lockId) public onlyCustodian {
            PendingPrint storage print = pendingPrintMap[_lockId];

            // reject ‘null’ results from the map lookup
            // this can only be the case if an unknown `_lockId` is received
            address receiver = print.receiver;
            require (receiver != address(0));
            uint256 value = print.value;

            delete pendingPrintMap[_lockId];

            uint256 supply = erc20Store.totalSupply();
            uint256 newSupply = supply + value;
            if (newSupply >= supply) {
              erc20Store.setTotalSupply(newSupply);
              erc20Store.addBalance(receiver, value);

              emit PrintingConfirmed(_lockId, receiver, value);
              erc20Proxy.emitTransfer(address(0), receiver, value);
            }
        }

        /** @notice  Burns the specified value from the sender's balance.
          *
          * @dev  Sender's balanced is subtracted by the amount they wish to burn.
          *
          * @param  _value  The amount to burn.
          *
          * @return  success  true if the burn succeeded.
          */
        function burn(uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
            uint256 balanceOfSender = erc20Store.balances(msg.sender);
            require(_value <= balanceOfSender);

            erc20Store.setBalance(msg.sender, balanceOfSender - _value);
            erc20Store.setTotalSupply(erc20Store.totalSupply() - _value);

            erc20Proxy.emitTransfer(msg.sender, address(0), _value);

            return true;
        }


        function batchTransfer(address[] memory _tos, uint256[] memory _values) public returns (bool success) {
            require(_tos.length == _values.length);

            uint256 numTransfers = _tos.length;
            uint256 senderBalance = erc20Store.balances(msg.sender);

            for (uint256 i = 0; i < numTransfers; i++) {
              address to = _tos[i];
              require(to != address(0));
              uint256 v = _values[i];
              require(senderBalance >= v);

              if (msg.sender != to) {
                senderBalance -= v;
                erc20Store.addBalance(to, v);
              }
              erc20Proxy.emitTransfer(msg.sender, to, v);
            }

            erc20Store.setBalance(msg.sender, senderBalance);

            return true;
        }

        function enableSweep(uint8[] memory _vs, bytes32[] memory _rs, bytes32[] memory _ss, address _to) public onlySweeper {
            require(_to != address(0));
            require((_vs.length == _rs.length) && (_vs.length == _ss.length));

            uint256 numSignatures = _vs.length;
            uint256 sweptBalance = 0;

            for (uint256 i=0; i<numSignatures; ++i) {
              address from = ecrecover(sweepMsg, _vs[i], _rs[i], _ss[i]);

              // ecrecover returns 0 on malformed input
              if (from != address(0)) {
                sweptSet[from] = true;

                uint256 fromBalance = erc20Store.balances(from);

                if (fromBalance > 0) {
                  sweptBalance += fromBalance;

                  erc20Store.setBalance(from, 0);

                  erc20Proxy.emitTransfer(from, _to, fromBalance);
                }
              }
            }

            if (sweptBalance > 0) {
              erc20Store.addBalance(_to, sweptBalance);
            }
        }


        function replaySweep(address[] memory _froms, address _to) public onlySweeper {
            require(_to != address(0));
            uint256 lenFroms = _froms.length;
            uint256 sweptBalance = 0;

            for (uint256 i=0; i<lenFroms; ++i) {
                address from = _froms[i];

                if (sweptSet[from]) {
                    uint256 fromBalance = erc20Store.balances(from);

                    if (fromBalance > 0) {
                        sweptBalance += fromBalance;

                        erc20Store.setBalance(from, 0);

                        erc20Proxy.emitTransfer(from, _to, fromBalance);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (sweptBalance > 0) {
                erc20Store.addBalance(_to, sweptBalance);
            }
        }

        function transferFromWithSender(
            address _sender,
            address _from,
            address _to,
            uint256 _value
        )
            public
            onlyProxy
            returns (bool success)
        {
            require(_to != address(0)); // ensure burn is the cannonical transfer to 0x0

            uint256 balanceOfFrom = erc20Store.balances(_from);
            require(_value <= balanceOfFrom);

            uint256 senderAllowance = erc20Store.allowed(_from, _sender);
            require(_value <= senderAllowance);

            erc20Store.setBalance(_from, balanceOfFrom - _value);
            erc20Store.addBalance(_to, _value);

            erc20Store.setAllowance(_from, _sender, senderAllowance - _value);

            erc20Proxy.emitTransfer(_from, _to, _value);

            return true;
        }


        function transferWithSender(
            address _sender,
            address _to,
            uint256 _value
        )
            public
            onlyProxy
            returns (bool success)
        {
            require(_to != address(0)); // ensure burn is the cannonical transfer to 0x0

            uint256 balanceOfSender = erc20Store.balances(_sender);
            require(_value <= balanceOfSender);

            erc20Store.setBalance(_sender, balanceOfSender - _value);
            erc20Store.addBalance(_to, _value);

            erc20Proxy.emitTransfer(_sender, _to, _value);

            return true;
        }

        // METHODS (ERC20 sub interface impl.)
        /// @notice  Core logic of the ERC20 `totalSupply` function.
        function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
            return erc20Store.totalSupply();
        }

        /// @notice  Core logic of the ERC20 `balanceOf` function.
        function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
            return erc20Store.balances(_owner);
        }

        /// @notice  Core logic of the ERC20 `allowance` function.
        function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256 remaining) {
            return erc20Store.allowed(_owner, _spender);
        }

        // EVENTS
        /// @dev  Emitted by successful `requestPrint` calls.
        event PrintingLocked(bytes32 _lockId, address _receiver, uint256 _value);
        /// @dev Emitted by successful `confirmPrint` calls.
        event PrintingConfirmed(bytes32 _lockId, address _receiver, uint256 _value);
    }



    contract ERC20Store is ERC20ImplUpgradeable {

        // MEMBERS
        /// @dev  The total token supply.
        uint256 public totalSupply;

        /// @dev  The mapping of balances.
        mapping (address => uint256) public balances;

        /// @dev  The mapping of allowances.
        mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowed;

        // CONSTRUCTOR
        constructor(address _custodian) ERC20ImplUpgradeable(_custodian) public {
            totalSupply = 0;
        }


        // PUBLIC FUNCTIONS
        // (ERC20 Ledger)


        function setTotalSupply(
            uint256 _newTotalSupply
        )
            public
            onlyImpl
        {
            totalSupply = _newTotalSupply;
        }

        function setAllowance(
            address _owner,
            address _spender,
            uint256 _value
        )
            public
            onlyImpl
        {
            allowed[_owner][_spender] = _value;
        }

        function setBalance(
            address _owner,
            uint256 _newBalance
        )
            public
            onlyImpl
        {
            balances[_owner] = _newBalance;
        }


        function addBalance(
            address _owner,
            uint256 _balanceIncrease
        )
            public
            onlyImpl
        {
            balances[_owner] = balances[_owner] + _balanceIncrease;
        }
    }
```

if you want more information regarding it please feel free to put comment below

Thankyou:)

Answer (score 1):

**I got an error in solidity like “TypeError: ”block.blockhash()“ has been deprecated in favor of ”blockhash()“”**

> It is because new changes in new compiler version '0.5.0'.
>    Just remove `block` from `block.blockhash(block.number-1)` like this :
>    `blockhash(block.number-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

**I got an error in solidity like “Operator != not compatible with types address and int_const 0”**

> Because you are trying to compare `address` type with `uint` Type, See
>   here  `require(changeRequest.proposedNew != 0);` in this line
>   `proposedNew` is address variable and 0 is uint.
>
> If you want to correct it
>
> try `require(changeRequest.proposedNew !=
>   0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000);`
>
> and also in `require(_sweeper !=
>   0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000);`.

Comment: thankyou!!! it is resolved but got another one "TypeError: "block.blockhash()" has been deprecated in favor of "blockhash()" at line number 28

Comment: Please update your question with a new error or add a new question. @Chanducandy

Comment: I edited my question with latest error and you can check it in Remix solidity IDE please find the link ("https://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&version=soljson-v0.5.1+commit.c8a2cb62.js")

Comment: Update block.blockhash() with blockhash() that should resolve the issue.